# Check how many times a time range cross certain hour range

Tags: c#, .net, time, range

We are building a visitor parking permit system, the permits have start and end datetime and are linked to a resident.

An overnight is defined as completely crossing a hour range not just the midnight mark.  For example, if the parking permit crosses 10PM to 2:00AM or 2:00AM to 4:00AM then it's considered an overnight parking, this is customizable depending on how the system is configured.

I'm really having some trouble designing and writing the logic for this, any help would be appreciated.  The follow diagram shows what I want to count.  Black horizontal line is the length of the parking permit and then red line is the hour range.

The first parking permit uses 4 nights of parking and the second permit uses 6 nights.

Please note that all the hour range are the same for every day of the week, i used paint so the red lines aren't all the same.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "completely crossing a hour range"?  Does that mean the permit is for more than one hour?

Comment: if the permit is issued from 7-24-2014 6:00PM to 7-26-2014 5:00AM and an overnight is defined as 11PM to 7AM.  This means it has used 2 over night permits because on the 26th day, it did not cross over 7AM.  Basically our clients want to define what overnight parking means, not just passing the midnight mark.

Comment: If it didn't cross over the 7AM mark, why is it two overnights?  Wouldn't it be one overnight, for the night of the 24th/morning of the 25th?  The night of the 25th/morning of the 26th wouldn't count as an overnight since they didn't stay until 7AM.

Comment: sorry you are correct, it should be one overnight....any recommendations on what's the best way to store these data and what the best practice to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

so you have resident, permit, and overnight tables.  The permit table has the resident as a FK and a start and end datetime.  the overnight table has a start time and end time, assuming 'Overnight' is defined the same way each day of the week.

Then to determine if a permit spans an overnight range, you check if
permitBegin <= overnightEnd AND permitEnd >= overnightBegin.

Is that the kind of help you're looking for?

Comment: the overnight table can be 2AM to 4AM or 10PM to 4:00AM and I can't compare date type with time in c# and the permit can span multiple days which makes it harder to compare.  I also need to know how many overnights per permit.

Comment: so the overnight table can have multiple rows?  that's ok, just determine the value for each row individually, then you can sum to get the total.  You're using C# for the front end, right, not the back end?  You're saying your back end doesn't support a datetime data type?

Comment: the issue is that the overnight time can span from the previous day to the next day basically i have to go through each day from permit star to permit end and then form a datetime using the time span and then compare..

Comment: not sure why that's a problem, so overnight start is 1/1/2014 11:00 PM to 1/2/2014 1:00 AM.  Permit start is either before or after 1/2/2014 1:00 AM, permit end either before or after overnight start.